# Sorting a list of dicts based on another list of dicts in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have 2 lists

```
A = [{'g': 'goal'}, {'b': 'ball'}, {'a': 'apple'}, {'f': 'float'}, {'e': 'egg'}]
B = [{'a': None}, {'e': None}, {'b': None}, {'g': None}, {'f': None}]
```

I want to sort A according to B. The reason I'm asking this is, I can't simply copy B's contents into A and over-writing A's object values with None. I want to retain A's values but sort it according to B's order.

How do I achieve this? Would prefer a solution in Python

Comment: Why do you have a list of one-key dicts anyway? This sounds like a job for one OrderedDict, or maybe a list of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spots = {next(iter(d)): i for i, d in enumerate(B)}
sorted_A = [None] * len(A)
for d in A:
    sorted_A[spots[next(iter(d))]] = d
```

Average-case linear time. Place each dict directly into the spot it needs to go, without slow `index` calls or even calling `sorted`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Create a lookup dict on `A` and then use `B`'s keys to create a new list in the right order.

```
In [103]: lookup_list = {k : d for d in A for k in d}

In [104]: sorted_list = [lookup_list[k] for d in B for k in d]; sorted_list
Out[104]: [{'a': 'apple'}, {'e': 'egg'}, {'b': 'ball'}, {'g': 'goal'}, {'f': 'float'}]
```

---

#### Performance

Setup:

```
import random
import copy

x = list(range(10000)) 
random.shuffle(x)

A = [{str(i) : 'test'} for i in x] 
B = copy.deepcopy(A)
random.shuffle(B)

# user2357112's solution
%%timeit
spots = {next(iter(d)): i for i, d in enumerate(B)}
sorted_A = [None] * len(A)
for d in A:
    sorted_A[spots[next(iter(d))]] = d

# Proposed in this post
%%timeit
lookup_list = {k : d for d in A for k in d}
sorted_list = [lookup_list[k] for d in B for k in d]; sorted_list
```

Results:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 9.27 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.92 ms per loop
```

45% speedup to the original `O(n)`, with twice the space complexity.

Comment: All those `index` calls make this run in quadratic time overall.

Comment: @user2357112 Figured out a better solution in O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the indices of keys in a dictionary and use those in the [sorting function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted). This would work in `O(n log(n))` time:

```
>>> keys = {next(iter(v)): i for i, v in enumerate(B)}
>>> keys
{'a': 0, 'e': 1, 'b': 2, 'g': 3, 'f': 4}    
>>> A.sort(key=lambda x: keys[next(iter(x))])
>>> A
[{'a': 'apple'}, {'e': 'egg'}, {'b': 'ball'}, {'g': 'goal'}, {'f': 'float'}]
```

Comment: Not O(n), because it's calling `sorted`. Still beats O(n**2), though.

Comment: Yes, it's `O(n log(n))`. However, for small inputs using `sorted()` may well be faster than pure Python `O(n)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid sorting by iterating over the existing, ordered keys in `B`:

1. Merge list `A` into a single lookup dict
2. Build a new list from the order in `B`, using the lookup dict to find the value matching each key

Code:

```
import itertools

merged_A = {k: v for d in A for k, v in d.items()}
sorted_A = [{k: merged_A[k]} for k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(B)]
# [{'a': 'apple'}, {'e': 'egg'}, {'b': 'ball'}, {'g': 'goal'}, {'f': 'float'}]
```

---

If required, you can preserve the original dict objects from `A` instead of building new ones:

```
keys_to_dicts = {k: d for d in A for k in d}
sorted_A = [keys_to_dicts[k] for k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(B)]
```

Comment: `sum` is a really bad (quadratic time) way to concatenate lists. Building the lookup table from A and then using it in a pass over B is nicer than what I did with the lookup table built from B and used in a pass over A, though.

Comment: Good call on using `itertools`.  I think `chain.from_iterable` will flatten that list.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Ah, whoops. I keep forgetting that. Thanks for reminding me.